# Select and apply class to multiple divs with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a list of items with markup that looks similar to this:

```
<article class="day past">
  <div class="schedule schedule-261 event">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</article>
<article class="day past">
  <div class="schedule schedule-283 event">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</article>
<article class="day past">
  <div class="schedule schedule-290 event">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</article>
<article class="day past">
  <div class="schedule schedule-261 event">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</article>
<article class="day past">
  <div class="schedule schedule-290 event">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</article>
<article class="day past">
  <div class="schedule schedule-300 event">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</article>
<article class="day past">
  <div class="schedule schedule-261 event">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

The `schedule-NUMBER` class is assigned based on the item's ID in a database. Basically, this is markup from a calendar that has repeating events, so some of the events will share the same database record.

If an item is "repeating" (ie. more than one div with `schedule-261` exists), I'd like to add/remove an extra class on hover in/out for all of `schedule-261` divs. If an item is not "repeating" (ie. there's only one div with `schedule-283`), then no extra class is applied on hover.

jQuery is the library of choice for this particular project, so a jQuery solution is preferred.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".schedule").each(function() {
    var cls = (this.className.match(/schedule-\d+/) || []).pop();
    if (cls.length === 0) return;

    var els = $(".schedule." + cls);
    if (els.not(this).length > 0) {
        els.hover(function() {
            els.addClass("someClass");
        }, function() {
            els.removeClass("someClass");
        });
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DSYpA/

Comment: Thanks, VisioN. For whatever reason (still a novice), I was unaware of [the JavaScript pop method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('article .schedule').on('mouseover', function () {

    var s = $(this); 
    if(s.size()>1) {
       s.addClass('myHoverClass');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the "schedule-[Number]" class and add the styling class:

```
$(".schedule").on("someevent", function(){
    var className = this.className;
    var classes = className.split(" ");
    for(var i=0;i<classes.length;i++)
    {
        var cls = classes[i];
        if (cls.indexOf("schedule") != -1 && cls.replace("schedule").length !== 0 && $("." + cls).length > 1)
        {
              $("." + cls).addClass("whatever");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.schedule').each(function()
{
   var s=this.className.split(/\s+/).filter(function(w){return /schedule-\d+/.test(w);});
   if (s && $('.' + s).length > 1) $('.' + s).addClass('yourclass');  
});
```